# Torch.Min in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, torch

In torch there is a module named, torch.Min, that can apply the min operation over different branches of a network.

> [nn.Min](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/simple.md#nn.Min)

is there something similar in tensorflow?. (noob in tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [tf.reduce_min](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_min). To find the min of `[10, 3, 5, 4]`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def one_dim_graph():
  input_tensor = tf.constant([10, 3, 5, 4])
  tensor_min = tf.reduce_min(input_tensor)
  return input_tensor, tensor_min


def run():
  in_one, g_one = one_dim_graph()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    out_one = sess.run([g_one])
    print in_one
    print out_one


run()
```

This will give you the min:

```
Tensor("Const_74:0", shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
[3]
```

You can also use this across multi-dimension tensors and reduce all dimensions or reduce along a certain dimension. So, for example, to find the min of:

```
[[1, 4, 3, 10],
 [6, 5, 2, 12],
 [9, 7, 8, 11]]
```

We can find:

- the total min, `[1]` with `tf.reduce_min(input_tensor)`
- the column-wise min `[1, 4, 2, 10]` with `tf.reduce_min(input_tensor, reduction_indices=0)`
- the row-wise min `[1, 2, 7]` with `tf.reduce_min(input_tensor, reduction_indices=1)`